# Final Form - useField hook validator

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-final-form

I am trying to add a form field that is built with useField. I also want to dynamically turn off the required validation depending if the field is disabled or not. Even though the component is being re-rendered, the validation is not removed.

Here is an example
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-zhukovsky-woicvh?file=/index.js

**index.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Form } from "react-final-form";
import TextField from "./TextField";

const App = () => {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);
  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    alert("Submit Successful");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>{isDisabled ? "is" : "is not"} disabled</div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={(value) => setIsDisabled(value.target.checked)}
      />
      <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
              <TextField
                name="firstName"
                type="text"
                placeholder="First Name"
                disabled={isDisabled}
                required={!isDisabled}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**TextField.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useField } from "react-final-form";

const requiredValidator = (value) =>
  !value || !value.length ? "required" : false;

const TextField = ({ label, ...props }) => {
  const { required, ...rest } = props;

  const { input, meta } = useField(props.name, {
    validate: required ? requiredValidator : null
  });

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        {label}
        <input {...input} {...rest} />
      </label>
      {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
    </>
  );
};
export default TextField;
```

By ticking the box, it disables/enables the text box, which should in turn remove the validation. i.e disabled box = not required

But it is always required, I dont understand why.